# Doubt in the working of inductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

my teacher told me that ,when **current first enters an inductor it will produce a current in the opposite direction to the one entering and the net current initially would be $0$ according to Lenz's law ,and the opposing current produced would decrease with time and gradually the current builds up in the circuit**

My doubt is how would the current in the circuit increase gradually.The opposing current produced is just instantaneous right?because if the flux through the loops become constant the opposing current would be $0$.
So should current in the circuit be building up instantaneously?

What us wrong in my concept?

I am a high school student so please keep the answer simple.

Comment: Flux doesn't become constant instantly, it increases gradually and approaches a constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a current starts to flow, there is an induced voltage $V = -L\frac{dI}{dt}$. The minus sign means that it is against the current flow.

But in my opinion it is confusing to think of a current that flows in the opposite direction, and that decreases with time. There is only one current, and that increases until its final value. (I think here of DC current).

The [analogies electrical mechanical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies) are useful. In this case, current is like velocity, induction like mass and voltage like force.

The situation is similar as to push a mass without friction. The induced voltage is like the reaction force: $F = -m\frac{dv}{dt}$. While there is any contact, there is a reaction force. When we release the mass, it keeps a constant velocity, that corresponds to a constant current, following  the analogy.

Comment: What is meant by "reaction force"?

Comment: When we do a force on a mass, the mass reacts back with the same force on us, in the opposite direction.